# Can AutoMapper Map Between a Value Type (Enum) and Reference Type? (string)

Tags: c#, enums, automapper, value-type, reference-type

Weird problem - i'm trying to map between an **enum** and a **string**, using AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum, string>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ToString()));
```

Don't worry that im using `.ToString()`, in reality i'm using an extension method on the enum itself (`.ToDescription()`), but i've kept it simple for the sake of the question.

The above throws an **object reference** error, when im doing simply setting up the mapping.

Considering this works:

```
string enumString = MyEnum.MyEnumType.ToString();
```

I can't see why my AutoMapper configuration does not.

Can AutoMapper handle this, am i doing something wrong, or is this a bug with AutoMapper?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I also tried using a **custom resolver:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum, string>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MyEnumResolver>());

public class MyEnumResolver: ValueResolver<MyEnum,string>
{
   protected override string ResolveCore(MyEnum source)
   {
      return source.ToString();
   }
}
```

Same error on same line. :(

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For mapping between two types where you're taking control of the entire mapping, use ConvertUsing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum, string>().ConvertUsing(src => src.ToString());
```

All the other methods assume you're mapping to individual members on the destination type.

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense. Because i was doing `.ForMember`, but im not actually trying to map the member, im trying to map the entire object. Works great - thanks! +1 and accepted.

Comment: Really great solution...!